# Anime about people fighting blob in building

Tags: story-identification, anime

It was something I saw a preview of a few years ago so it’s a newer anime, at least the last 4 to 5 years.  The characters in the trailer were in a giant skyscraper running away from a growing blob that was chasing them through the building.  They were skating around on basically roller skates but way more badass and would turn around and shoot at the blob to slow it’s progress as the skates backwards.  At one point one of the characters gets attacked and taken into the blobby mass and you think he’s dead till they show that he was using a fake body from a remote location.  It was a very colorful anime and I’d really enjoy it if someone could help me find it.  I’ve googled every key word I can think of to find it but only super old anime’s about blob monsters or roller skating come up.

Answer (score 3):

This is [A.I.C.O. -Incarnation-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.I.C.O._-Incarnation-). The opening scene has a crew of hacker thieves breaking into a building, then being confronted by a gigantic growing blob thing. They escape at speed on rollerskates.